# How can I enable keep alive (Not accessing to Apache)

Tags: htaccess

I am monitoring my website ([faghatseo.com](http://faghatseo.com)) seeing an error about keep alive. I googled this problem, as an solution, there was a code

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Connection keep-alive 
</IfModule>
```

that you had to place in the **.htaccess** file in this direction below: 
**/public_html/.htaccess**

when I placed the code, error 500 appeared and my website went down!

> Internal Server Error
>   The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>   [image]
>   The error is like this
>
> Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@faghatseo.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
>
> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Obviously, I do not have access to Apache cause i'm using shared hosting service.

Is there any other way to enable keep alive with Cpanel or something?

Comment: keep alive has to be used in some cases , you have to make sure you need it first ..

Answer (score 1):

Check out [`wp_headers`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_headers/) filter:

```
/**
 * Filter WordPress headers before sent
 *
 * @see  https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_headers/
 */
function wpse_289493($headers, $wp)
{
    foreach ($headers as $key => $value) {
        if ('connection' === strtolower($key)) {
            unset($headers[$key]);
        }
    }

    $headers['Connection'] = 'Keep-Alive';

    return $headers;
}

// Add filter
add_filter('wp_headers', 'wpse_289493', 10, 2);
```